# Image is blurry when upscaling in Mobile Safari

Tags: css, mobile-safari, css-transforms

I'm implementing a Pinch to Zoom gesture in JS/CSS. In order to do so, I'm putting a fairly large image source inside a small sized `IMG` tag and then apply a CSS scale transform to make it bigger. 
Things are working fine however on Mobile Safari the image gets blurry once I start scaling up. It should not be the case as the `src` for the image is big enough to support this size, but somehow Mobile Safari is displayed it as blurry.

I have debugged the issue quite a bit and found out that the culprit is an unrelated div in my page that is setting `translate3d(0,0,0)`. To my understanding this is a Hack to trigger GPU hardware acceleration. What I believe it is happening is that because of `translate3d(0,0,0)`, hardware acceleration is being applied when rendering the `<img/>`, and since the `<img>` is small in size, it is drawn small and the scale is applied afterwards.

To better understand the problem, I have it this code, available in [in codepen here](https://codepen.io/mcohnen/pen/rNBGKQP)

HTML

```
<div>
  <div id="translate3d-div"/>
</div>

<img id="image" src="https://www.trackalytics.com/assets/thumbnails/lipsum.com.jpg"/>
```

CSS

```
#translate3d-div {
  /* If I remove this, the image is not blurry */
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
}

#image {
  width: 95px;
  height:76px;
  transform: scale(20);
}
```

This displays the image blurry on Mobile Safari, but it works fine on Chrome in Android.

Is there a way to fix this other than removing the unrelated `translate3d`? I don't think I can do that since it might be used by some other feature in the webpage.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find a working hack for this, but the workaround I used was to simply create a bigger HTMLImageElement and scale it down initially. Then scaled up it will not look blurry. This made my code slightly more complicated but it is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

This is because how WebKit renders transforms when hardware acceleration is enabled (like in iPhone). It increases performance dramatically but affects antialiasing when you apply a 3DTransform when no real transformation happens.

A hackfix is to set a background for the element.

```
 #translate3d-div {
   transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   background: transparent;
 }
```

Source: https://dropshado.ws/post/6142339613/resolving-anti-aliasing-on-webkit

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation. However, the hack does not seem to work. I just tested it on my iPhone using this codepen: https://codepen.io/mcohnen/pen/JjPBzmp I tried adding `background: transparent` to both the div with the transform and the `img` being affected by it.

Comment: Uhm, yeah, you're right. It seems my iPhone rendered it again when I live-edited the code.

If this doesn't work it must be what you thought first: the scale transformation is  messing it up. Is there any reason you need it to be applied on the `img` tag? It seems to work if you set width and height on the parent div.

Comment: It is the image what I want to scale up. I tried wrapping it up in a `div` that will have the width/height set and the transform applied to it, but I still get the same behavior: https://codepen.io/mcohnen/pen/PoYBLvM The only solution I can think of is making the `img` Element bigger and applying an initial `scaleDown` effect. This makes my code way messier but it is the workaround I'm contemplating at the moment.